# MongoDB findOne but exclude some field - not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to **MongoDB**

I tried the **findOne** function, but it does not work the way I want it

```
client.db("game").collection("players").findOne({ _id: "s1" }, { data: 1, _id: 0 })
```

I want it to return only the **data** field without the **_id**

but it returns:

```
{
  _id: 's1',
  data: [somedata...]
}
```

My data is look like this (From MongoDB Compass):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB Version 5.0.6 the MongoDB query is working fine
[Output Of The Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVBmH.png)

Comment: I tried it, but not sure why it's not working for me,
Now I used **projection** it solved the problem for me
`findOne({ _id: "s1" }, { projection: { data: 1, _id: 0 } })`